# WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE ignores ON filter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL proc in a web service that accepts a collection of user data and performs the following:

1. If the user does not exist at destination, insert it
2. If the user exists in destination, update with any new details from source
3. If the user does not exist in source, then archive them in destination

There is a problem with the last part (`WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN UPDATE`) in the sense that EVERY row in the table is updated to have `archived=1`.  I assumed that only rows with `customerId` matching that of `@customerId` would be affected, but its updating all rows except those matched in `ON` and ignoring the `ON` filter.

```
MERGE
    [tbl_Users] AS tgt -- Target
USING
    #tbl_working AS src -- Source
ON
    (tgt.customerID = @customerId) AND
    (tgt.employeeID = src.EmployeeId) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET -- user exists; update
    tgt.username = src.username
    tgt.name = src.FirstName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT -- user does not exist; create
    (
    customerID,
    username,
    name
    ) 
    VALUES 
    (
    @customerId,
    src.UserName,
    src.Name
    )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN UPDATE -- user no longer required; archive
    SET tgt.archived = 1;
```

I might not be using the last part correctly, so would appreciate any input please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just want to add an extra condition:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND tgt.customerID = @CustomerID
   THEN UPDATE -- user no longer required; archive
        SET tgt.archived = 1;
```

The `ON` clause is just used to decide how your `source` and `target` are matched up. By the time of the `WHEN ...` clauses, it's already done its job. It doesn't stick around and *selectively* apply to anything else.

---

It may help to realise that the `MERGE` statement *potentially* affects every row in the `target` table.

Let's say that what happens is we split the `source` table into two sets of rows - `sm` being the rows that match rows in the `target` table via the `ON` clause, and `su` being all remaining rows in the `source`.

Let's say we also split the `target` table into two sets of rows - `tm` being the rows that match rows in the `source` table and `tu` being all remaining rows in the `target`.

A `WHEN MATCHED` clause is dealing with the sets of rows `sm` and `tm`, and working out what to do about them.

`WHEN NOT MATCHED IN TARGET` is dealing with the set of rows `su`.

`WHEN NOT MATCHED IN SOURCE` is dealing with the set of rows `tu`.

You don't need to add the `AND tgt.customerID = @CustomerID` condition to `WHEN MATCHED` because that condition was already used to determine which rows are in `su` and which are in `sm` (and `tu`, and `tm`).

You *do* want this extra condition in your `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause because you actually want to further divide the `tu` set and not affect all of those rows.

---

Another alternative you might want to consider is that you can filter your target table first and then apply the merge against that:

```
;WITH CustomerUsers as (
    SELECT * FROM tbl_Users where customerID = @customerID
)
MERGE
    CustomerUsers AS tgt -- Target
USING
    #tbl_working AS src -- Source
ON
    (tgt.employeeID = src.EmployeeId) 
...
```

And now everything discussed above about `target` is only actually dealing with "the subset of rows from `tbl_Users` that belong to `@customerID`"

Comment: you're a superstar!  I'm not sure I follow though.  Why should the clause stop at the last part, but yet be applied as intended for `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE`?  Or should this line also be updated to `WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.customerID = @customerID THEN UPDATE`